# Earliest use of adjunction spaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, math-history

An *adjunction space* is a topological space $Y= B \cup _f X$ determined by an inclusion $i : A \to X$ and a map $f: A \to B$; it can  be described briefly as the *pushout*  of the two maps $f,i$. The advantage of this notion is that it is behind the J.H.C. Whitehead notion of CW-complex, which is about inductively attaching cells $E^n$ by means of maps $S^{n-1} \to X_{n-1}$. Good properties of $A,X,B$ are often carried over to $Y$ (eg being Hausdorff).  The pushout property allows one to construct continuous functions on $Y$. { cf [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html)).

The earliest paper I have on this notion is by Whitehead: "Note on a Theorem due to Borsuk",  Bull AMS (1948) 1125-1137. I would be grateful for information on earlier reference to this notion.

Comment: According to Engelking, General Topology, Historical and bibliographic notes of section 2.4, adjunction spaces were defined by [Borsuk in 1935](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/24/0/93200/quelques-retractes-singuliers) (for compact metric spaces)

Comment: Thanks a lot:.I've just printed it out!

Comment: @Ulli Why not an official answer?

Comment: The information is in the second edition of Engilking's book!

Answer (score 3):

Since I was asked to state an official answer, here it is, although it's just copy paste from Engelking's book:

According to Engelking, General Topology, Historical and bibliographic notes of section 2.4, adjunction spaces were defined by [Borsuk in 1935](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/24/0/93200/quelques-retractes-singuliers) (for compact metric spaces)